# Band gap theory of semiconductors

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

Is there any change in the band structure or band gap of nano semiconductors from that of bulk semiconductors and if yes how that happens?

Comment: Yes, this is the entire basis of how [[quantum dots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_dot) work

Comment: What is your definition of a nano semiconductor?

Answer (score 1):

The bandgap of a single crystal semiconductor is in a simplified view determined by the bond strength (corresponding to the depth of the potential well of each binding orbital) and by the spacing of the atoms (corresponding to the lattice constant).

Now the bandgap can be different for nanostructured materials if they have a different crystal structure or lattice constant, which is definitely observed for different materials (although it is not a general condition). One example are zincblende/wurtzite polymorphism in GaAs. Bulk GaAs crystallizes in a zincblende lattice, while nanowires tend to form wurtzite and therfore have a slightly different bandgap.

Note that quantum-mechanical confinement of electronic wavefunctions due to a nanometer sized geometry does shift photoluminescence or absorption spectra but does not change the materials bandgap in that sense.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to say in your last paragraph.  If the spectra changes, the bandgap has changed.  If you are referring to the phase transition ... I don't think the OP is about phase transitions.

Comment: I'm not referring to the phase transition. I just wanted to stress that energy shifts due to quantum confinement or due to a change in the bandgap are different effects.

Comment: Hmm.  Well this is muddy because confinement will change the bandgap.